# I encoded HEX String for javascript how to implement it?

Tags: javascript, encryption, hex, tampermonkey

I encoded HEX String for javascript how to implement it?
i used https://www.tools4noobs.com/online_tools/encrypt/
modes : twofish

**After i encrypted my code, i got big and log lines of codes.
 how can i put it in my tampermonkey userscript?

if impossible how can i encrypt my javascript code because i dont want people stealing my script.**

The code is like `166acbd7c5dcc51eff5ca2d42640d2668518ba74b5714322c401a563ac63064abca2e5676fb35c1657fd3`

Is there any way?

Comment: Run it server side and AJAX it from your client side.

Comment: a) What is your definition of "code"? The `166acbd7c5d...` thing is not code, but rather a Hex-encoded string of something. The common definition of code is a language that instructs the computer to do something. Perhaps you mean "ciphertext". b) If you want to put a secret (`166acbd7c5d...`) in you JavaScript code, then encryption doesn't give you any security, because the decryption key must also be available. Perhaps you're looking for obfuscation? c) What does this all have to do with twofish and the web site you're citing?

Comment: @ArtjomB. i need to just obfuscation my javascript thats all.

Comment: This is a fool's errand. There is NOTHING you can do to stop anyone who knows JS from getting your code (except don't publish at all).  See the duplicate question and the dozens of other questions that cover this topic.